# If $A= \begin{pmatrix} -4 & 1\\ 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ find $f(A)$ if $f(x) =x^2 - 2x+3$

Tags: matrices

If $A= \begin{pmatrix} -4 & 1\\ 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ find $f(A)$ if $f(x) =x^2 - 2x+3$.

Actually while solving for $f(A)$, my teacher said to change $3$ into $3I$ where $I$ is an identity matrix, so that matrix can add up but I am still confused about how can an integer change into the matrix and what is its significance?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: Do you mean $\begin{bmatrix} -4&1 \\ 3&2\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Where did "7" come from?  Do you mean replace $3$ by $3I$?

Answer (score 1):

I agree ... arbitrarily changing a number into a matrix doesn't make much sense, and you're right to question it.

In my opinion, the problem is just poorly written, and you shouldn't worry about that. The function $f$ is pointless, and doesn't need to be mentioned at all. What the problem is really asking you to do is calculate $A^2 - 2A + 3I$, and I expect you know how to do that.

Comment: Changing a number into a matrix seems to be a convention used in, for example, the Cayley-Hamilton theorem. (If $P(X) = X^2 + 1$ is the characteristic polynomial, then $P(A) = A^2 + I$.) This notation can be confusing for first-timers, as was for me. But as for the OP's question, this is just a definition/conventional issue. There is a way of thinking about such things via isomorphisms.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a convention. But it's a convention that deserves some explanation. Telling a beginner to just interchange numbers and matrices willy nilly  is inviting confusion, and I think the OP is right to question it.